# Facing issue while adding media in core

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-9

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'sdfasernfjsdnfur jfhewruthwert' for column 'revision_log_message' at row 1: INSERT INTO "media_revision" ("mid", "langcode", "revision_user", "revision_created", "revision_log_message", "revision_default") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 26 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1681751811 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => sdfasernfjsdnfur jfhewruthwert [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 815 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Tried to uploading any image or doc file and adding revisions but facing issues.